# How to retrieve a single value from a list of records in neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I am pretty new to Neo4j. I have written this piece of code below:

```
List<Value> collect_appnames = new ArrayList<Value>();
Driver  dr = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://inmbzp5137.in.dst.ibm.com:7687", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", " "));
Session session = dr.session();
StatementResult rs = session.run("Match(n:Application) with n.name as a return distinct collect(a)");
Assert.assertTrue(rs.hasNext());
while(rs.hasNext()) {
    Record record = rs.next();
    collect_appnames= record.values();
}
```

collect_appnames returns this->

```
[
  [
    "sample-tomcat",
    "sampleticketing",
    "sampleoms",
    "samplescheduler",
    "sampleinventory",
    "samplerating",
    "sampleloyalty",
    "samplertcm",
    "sampleproducts",
    "sampleinvoicegenerator",
    "samplejbosswildfly",
    "samplewebsphereapplication",
    "samplereports",
    "sampleapplication",
    "samplebanking",
    "samplemoneytransfer",
    "sampleautomobile",
    "samplemanufacturing",
    "sampleinvestment",
    "samplesavings",
    "sampledesign",
    "samplepatterns",
    "samplepatents",
    "sampleonlinetransfer",
    "samplerecharge",
    "samplecreditcheck",
    "samplecreditcheck",
    "sampleautomobileserver",
    "sample-tomcat",
    "sampleticketing",
    "sampleoms",
    "samplescheduler",
    "sampleinventory",
    "samplerating",
    "sampleloyalty",
    "samplertcm",
    "sampleproducts",
    "sampleinvoicegenerator",
    "samplejbosswildfly",
    "samplewebsphereapplication",
    "samplereports",
    "sampleapplication",
    "samplebanking",
    "samplemoneytransfer",
    "sampleautomobile",
    "samplemanufacturing",
    "sampleinvestment",
    "samplesavings",
    "sampledesign",
    "samplepatterns",
    "samplepatents",
    "sampleonlinetransfer",
    "samplerecharge",
    "sampleticketing",
    "sampleoms",
    "samplescheduler",
    "sampleinventory",
    "samplerating",
    "sampleloyalty",
    "sample-tomcat",
    "samplertcm",
    "sampleproducts",
    "sampleinvoicegenerator",
    "samplejbosswildfly",
    "samplewebsphereapplication",
    "samplereports",
    "sampleapplication",
    "samplebanking",
    "samplemoneytransfer",
    "sampleautomobile",
    "samplemanufacturing",
    "sampleinvestment",
    "samplesavings",
    "sampledesign",
    "samplepatterns",
    "samplepatents",
    "sampleonlinetransfer",
    "samplerecharge",
    "samplecreditcheck",
    "sampleautomobileserver"
  ]
]
```

However collect_appnames.size() returns 1. So when i do collect_appnames.get(0) it is returning me the entire set. I want to extract only sample-tomcat from this list. Please tell me how to do this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please take a minute to properly format the code in your question so that it's easier to read.

Comment: It looks like you have an array of an array... the outer array having a single element. Are you doing that on purpose? Have you tried accessing the elements in the inner array directly?

Comment: Why is your Cypher collecting all names, when you only want a specific name? And do you actually want the Cypher to return a count of the number of times that specific name is found?

Comment: I need all the app names and then check if a particular name is present in the list of appname records. I am doing this on purpose because that is a part of my validation. Can you suggest me a way of accessing each element in the inner list. It would be really helpful.